# Qt how to open Device Manager

Tags: windows, qt, qprocess, device-manager

I am trying to open device manager from a button on Qt Windows app.

What I tried:
Assigned the slot/signal to the button. And the method:

```
 QProcess *proc = new QProcess(this);
    QString cmdStr = "devmgmt.msc";
    proc->start(cmdStr);
    qDebug() << "btn clicked";
```

But nothing happens when I click it. btn clicked is displayed in console tho.

Edit: I tried also

```
cmdStr="mmc devmgmt.msc"
```

But also unable to open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok managed to get it to work by using QDesktopServices.

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/devmgmt.msc", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

And here are a list of other windows app that you might be interested:

System Info

Command Prompt

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe\"");
```

Control Panel

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\control.exe\"");
```

Magnifier

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/Magnify.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Registry Edit

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/regedt32.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Services

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/services.msc", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

System Info

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/msinfo32.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Settings

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/settings", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Explorer

```
system("explorer.exe");
```

Task Manager

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/Taskmgr.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Disk Cleanup

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cleanmgr.exe\"");
```

MsConfig

```
system("C:/Windows/System32/msconfig.exe");
```

Windows Remote

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/msra.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Resource Monitor

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\resmon.exe\"");
```

System Repair Discs

```
system("C:/Windows/System32/recdisc.exe");
```

Memory Diagnostics

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/MdSched.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

System Restore

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/rstrui.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Startup Folder

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Users/dclar.DESKTOP-JTNNAGR/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Run Command

```
system("c:/windows/system32/rundll32.exe shell32.dll,#61");
```

Drive Optimization

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\dfrgui.exe\"");
```

Disk Managment

```
system("C:/Windows/System32/diskmgmt.msc");
```

Computer Managment

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/CompMgmtLauncher.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Text Tuner

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cttune.exe\"");
```

Computer Services

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/dcomcnfg.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Device Manager

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/devmgmt.msc", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Direct X Diagnostics

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\dxdiag.exe\"");
```

File History

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\FileHistory.exe\"");
```

Blue Tooth Transfer

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\fsquirt.exe\"");
```

Add Hardware

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/hdwwiz.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Disc Label

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\label.exe\"");
```

Language Installer

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\lpksetup.exe\"");
```

Malicious Software remover

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\MRT.exe\"");
```

Narrator

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/Narrator.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

User Accounts

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/Netplwiz.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Windows Backup

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/sdclt.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Create Shared Folders

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/shrpubw.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

System Shutdown

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/shutdown.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Sticky Notes

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\StikyNot.exe\"");
```

System Reset

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Windows/System32/systemreset.exe", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Ease Of Access

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\Utilman.exe\"");
```

Word Pad

```
QProcess::startDetached("\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\write.exe\"");
```